# How to modify single.php in a child theme?

Tags: child-theme, single

My WordPress site uses a child-theme (of the default twenty-sixteen) and now I would like to insert a new line into the `single.php` file.

I know that it's better to use the `functions.php` file of the child-theme than inserting the new line directly into the parent theme's `single.php` file. (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

I would be grateful if somebody could show me how to do it properly. I would like to insert this line

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> " data-numposts="5"></div>
```

into the

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
```

element, right above the closing

```
</main>
```

tag in the `single.php` file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> your child theme
>   can override any file in the parent theme: *simply include a file of
>   the same name in the child theme directory, and it will override the
>   equivalent file in the parent theme directory when your site loads*.

with the exception:

> Unlike style.css, the `functions.php` of a child theme does not override its 
>   counterpart from the parent. Instead, it is loaded in addition to the parent’s > `functions.php`. (Specifically, it is loaded right before the parent’s file.)

[Source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Template_Files)

in your case, just copy `single.php` to your child theme and do your edits.